# Tracking multiple Facebook "Like" buttons on one page

Tags: javascript, facebook

On my blog I have a global "Like" button in the header embedded with this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="http://www.domain.com/blog/" send="false" layout="button_count" width="120" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

This shows up on every page of the site. In addition, I've got "Like" buttons for each post that appears on the site using this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="http://www.domain.com<? the_permalink() ?>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="55" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

In the `<head>` of all pages I include the Facebook script (I replaced my app ID with X's here):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

The buttons are working perfectly well, but I'm trying to interaction with these buttons and can't seem to get any feedback with any but the first (global) button. In a `scripts.js` file loaded at the bottom of the page I have this snippet of code for the tracking:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
    console.log(targetUrl);
    //_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
});
```

Only the first, global "Like" button will print the `targetUrl` to the console. The others on the page don't print anything to the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a URL to a mocked up page?  I'm slightly suspicious the individual posts might be in iframes, causing the issue.  That's because FB.Event.subscribe() should set up a global trigger for all likes on the page.  If you can't do that, you can try debugging by subscribing on a per-element basis.  For instance, presuming you're using jQuery, add an `id="likeBlogPost1234"` attribute to your `<fb:like ...>` tag and then do a `$('#likeBlogPost1234').subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) { console.log("Specific like button with URL: " + targetUrl); }`

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Site's still in the works, but the posts are't in iFrames.

Comment: Oh, whoops, made a mistake in the above mailer code.  You'll have to move the `subscribe(...)` inside of an `.each()` since jQuery doesn't know about the subscribe function, unless you've extended it appropriately.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site is still in the works, are your posts' URLs live on the Web? If not, that would explain your problem. Like Buttons only work correctly for URLs that Facebook can reach. If you're testing on a staging server, be sure that the Like Buttons are set to Like your staging URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/).